# Range function with step higher than stop

Tags: python, for-loop, range

Could someone explain me why the output is 22 here:

```
def fun():
    for x in range(22,23,24):
        print(x)
fun()
```

Comment: Because the third argument in the `range` function indicates the step. In this case, the range function never reaches any number greater than 22. Try printing `list(range(22,23,24))` to see what it contains.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani In this case the step does not matter.  The loop will only print 22 even if there is no step.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes of course. But, still, it's a matter of `step` since its default value is set to 1. I just assumed that the OP is not familiar with that the range function has a default value for step (1). So it would make it more clear if I just went right to the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for range is `range(start, stop, step)`

The range of numbers to be printed starts from `22`, to `23` (end point not included), in steps of `24`.

The first number is `22`, which gets printed.

The next number will be `22` + `24` = `46`, which is greater than `23`, so it doesn’t get printed and the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over a `range` which starts with `22`, ends **before** `23`, and makes steps of `24`.

---

To better understand what you are doing, try this:

```
>>> list(range(22,23,24))
[22]
```

You are starting from `22`, then doing a step of `24`, and you clearly exceeded the limit of `23` since you are at `46` with `22+24`.

---

I would suggest to read the documentation about [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)'s constructor.

```
range(start, stop[, step]) # This is the prototype of the constructor
```

Comment: Specifically it ends _before_ 23, because ranges are half-open.

Comment: Right, in this case it doesn't matter because of the enormous step, but for sure it's better to be clear.